Convertingt top custom command for memory usage by processes to AIX
I wrote a custom shell command using the top command, in order of getting the sum memory usage for all the processes of a given program (for example java*, mongodb*, etc..) in a Linux based servers:
top -b -n 1 | grep java* | awk '{mem = mem + $10} END {print mem}'
The breakdown of the above command is a follow:

top: command to list resource usage
-b: using batch mode
-n 1: setting the number of iterations to one
grep java*: only for processes which starts with java
awk '{mem = mem + $10} END {print mem}': ssum the memory usage values for all the process in the previous pipeline, with the ten
column which is the memory usage column

But for AIX based serves,
I can't use the top command, so I need to find an alternative command like topas, but I'm struggling with the syntax of it, as it seems that is not quite versatile as the top command, but I don't have the knowledge in AIX to confirm it.

Have you consider to use ps command?

@RomeoNinov, how?

AFAIK ps aux show a lot of column, including shared and private storage for process

@RomeoNinov, thanks i will check it.
